# 502 on Nginx after start CSF

Tags: django, nginx, firewall, gunicorn

I've installed gunicorn, django and nginx as described in this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn).

I've developed a function in django that adds a user in my database and it works perfectly!!

Now I've installed CSF (Config Server Firewall) and if I run it `csf -r`, the same function for adding a user doesn't work.

I see, in the error log of Nginx, this raw:

```
*2014/06/25 10:11:04 [error] 5396#0: *19 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 79.35.50.121, server: [MY_SERVER_NAME], request: POST /django/registerClient HTTP/1.1, upstream: [MY_IP_SERVER]:8001/django/registerClient, host: [MY_IP_SERVER]*
```

I underline that the function work without star csf.

Can anyone can explain to me why I get this problem?

Comment: A 502: Bad Gateway error means django is failing to generate a response. It either times out, or there is an error. Check your Gunicorn logs to find out why. Edit: I just noticed you installed a firewall, and have your upstream pointing to :8001. Make sure port 8001 is open on your firewall.

Comment: The port 8001 is open in my firewall setting. Have you any ideas for my problem?

Comment: If the problem only occurs with csf, then your problem is definitely that csf is creating a communication barrier between uWSGI and nginx. Depending on your server, you may want to look into something like iptables to solve your firewall requirements. Edit: I see that csf actually employs iptables. Maybe check what iptables is doing with `/sbin/iptables -L`.